# Problem in integrating Firebase-storage images in app

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to android and I am making an app that requires various HorizontalRecyclerView. I need to integrate the above with firebase storage.
I followed a tutorial that helped me achieve HorizontalRecyclerView but I need to get my images from firebase storage.I followed a tutorial to do same but failed. I want that the app downloads the images using firebase storage and then shows it. I manually upload images to firebase storage.

recyclerview in HomeActivity

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

listitem.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="Canada"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="15sp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Methods used

```
    private void getImages(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initImageBitmaps: preparing bitmaps.");

    mImageUrls.add("https://images-na.ssl-images- 
    amazon.com/images/I/61s3uG2iFkL._SX466_.jpg");
    mNames.add("Havasu Falls");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/tpsnoz5bzo501.jpg");
    mNames.add("Trondheim");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/qn7f9oqu7o501.jpg");
    mNames.add("Portugal");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mNames.add("Rocky Mountain National Park");


    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/0h2gm1ix6p501.jpg");
    mNames.add("Mahahual");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/k98uzl68eh501.jpg");
    mNames.add("Frozen Lake");


    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/glin0nwndo501.jpg");
    mNames.add("White Sands Desert");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.redd.it/obx4zydshg601.jpg");
    mNames.add("Austrailia");

    mImageUrls.add("https://i.imgur.com/ZcLLrkY.jpg");
    mNames.add("Washington");

    initRecyclerView();

}

private void initRecyclerView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerview");

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

enter code here
```

So, how should i approach this?

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code?

Comment: It isn't working. There are no crashes but the pictures don't show up. I tried changing url but all in vain

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get the refrence of the images and download the images using this refrence and then create an adapter object that delivers the image local path to the CircleImageView.